# Java Database Connection Cant Connect To Derby Database Netbeans 7.4

Tags: java, database, netbeans, derby

Im trying to connect to a derby database on netbeans but i get this error every time. I have done some research and seen that poeple have resolved this issue by editing the policy file but this has not helped me. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Tue Feb 11 11:49:08 EST 2014 : Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.
Tue Feb 11 11:49:09 EST 2014 : access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:1527" "listen,resolve")
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:1527" "listen,resolve")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkListen(SecurityManager.java:1134)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at javax.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(ServerSocketFactory.java:231)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.createServerSocket(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.blockingStart(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.executeWork(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl.main(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Well, this error isn't coming from trying to connect to your database, it is coming from trying to start the Network Server. Have you followed the instructions at https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/adminguide/tadminnetservbasic.html

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with netbeans 7.4. Try this:

1. Find out exactly where the java home is by executing this instruction from Netbeans 7.4:

   ```
   System.out.println(System.getProperty(“java.home”));
   ```

   In my case it was:

   ```
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre
   ```

   It was really important to find the right config folder.
2. Open the file

```
{your path}\lib\security\java.policy
```

It should be something like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\security\java.policy
```

You may need administrator privileges.
3. Add this line into the grant block:

```
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:1527", "listen,resolve";
```

Save the file and try to connect to your DB.

Hope this helps.